# How to properly style a phone number label?

Tags: ios, uilabel, phone-number, uifont, typography

I want to display a phone number using UILabel in my iOS app.

What are the best font settings to make the numbers look nice? I tried mono spaced but it does not feel right.

Comment: "make the numbers look nice" is pretty much opinion-based. Try asking this on [ux.se].

Comment: Try here with preview: [Number Fonts](https://www.dafont.com/alpha.php?lettre=a&text=123456789)

Comment: Is there no configuration for the system font especially for phone numbers?

Comment: I agree with @the4kman - this is not a Stack Overflow question. We don't do design here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UITextView` and in the inspector you can make the phone number detectable. It looks nice when it's clickable =]